# Нету метода Log в Debug

Tags: unity3d

Хочу вывести в консоль сообщение, но Unity говорит что нету метода Log в Debug. Я порылся и нашел аналог - Debug.print(). Вопрос, куда делся Log?

Comment: Ну вы бы код привели, гадать на кофейной гуще мы тут не умеем :)

Comment: Скорее всего Вы не подключили пространство имен "UnityEngine": `using UnityEngine;`